# Phantom DSL - Read followed by a write

Tags: phantom-dsl

I need to update a column, only if the current value satisfies a pre-condition. I tried the below,

```
def acceptDelivery(implicit sc: SecurityContext, ar: AcceptRequest) : Future[DeliveryResponse] = {
for {
  d <- Database.DeliveryForVendorModel.findDelivery(ar) if d.isDefined && d.get.isPending
  _ <- Database.acceptDelivery(d.get, sc.ownerId, sc.ownerName)
} yield buildAcceptResponse(d)
```

}

However, if the first future doesn't materialize it throws an exception. The findDelivery method returns `Future[Option[T]]`, where T gas an isPending method.

Comment: update.
      where(_.placedDate eqs placedDate).
      and(_.locationKey eqs "").
      and(_.vendorId).
      and(_.orderId eqs orderId).
      modify(_.status setTo "ACCEPTED").
      onlyIf(_.status is "PENDING")

Comment: Can this question be closed now? CAS was the way forward indeed.